# How do I make sure that my background services don't keep running when I kill my own app?

Tags: android, android-service

I'm using some services like `Google Maps` and `Text To Speech` and when I close my app, those same processes are running in the background even after my Android app is closed.

What can I do to make sure that my processes are finished when my app is not in the foreground?

Comment: post some code.. how you are using that services.??

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this will be like this

If you have a homescreen or any screen where you will be killing all activities/components, override the `onDestroy` and call `stopService` method

```
 @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        stopService(new Intent(this, AppLocationService.class));
    }
```

In this case my app will be running service named AppLocationService

Answer (score 0):

If you want kill service process forcefully, you can use following code:

Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());

Answer (score 0):

Youse guys are making this whole thing WAY more complicated than it needs to be. When a process dies, it should first kill off all its potential zombies. I mean really, why complicate things that are already too complex for the average user? Just shut down nicely and get out of the way. I know there are politicsl reasons you want to keep running, but you're just making it even more difficult for Joe Average. When he clicks SHUT DOWN APP, he expects you, as a good citizen to fully shut down. I mean, it's s not rocket brain surgery. Go away means you should just go away.

Comment: Add some example of that particular topic. so they can engage more with your text